# OpenCV Face Detection in a Imageview

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

In my Android studio project, i have a serious problem. I want to detect face in an Imported image using OpenCV.

The problem is, it returns nothing when the application is running, not even an error.

This is the code of my button.

```
            imgImportedImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            imgImportedImage.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmapOfImage = imgImportedImage.getDrawingCache();

            Mat mmGray = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmapOfImage, mmGray);

            MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

            if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
                int height = mmGray.rows();
                if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
                    mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
                }
            }

            CascadeClassifier mDetector = new CascadeClassifier();
            mDetector.load("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

            mDetector.detectMultiScale(mmGray, faces, 1.1, 3, 0, new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());

            Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++){
                Core.rectangle(mmGray, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 2);
                Toast.makeText(FdActivity.this, String.valueOf(facesArray[i]), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```